# Query lowercase table name through JDBC

Tags: java, oracle

I'm trying to query a table using JDBC `executeQuery`. In my Oracle database there is a table `table1` (lowercase) which contains column `col1` (lowercase too). Unfortunately I cannot alter it to uppercase (to be compliant with Oracle naming standard).

```
public ResultSet executeQuery (Connection con,String st) {
    ResultSet rs=null;
    Statement stmt=null;
        
    try {
        stmt=con.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(st);
        //rs.next();    
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //System.exit(1);
    }
        
    return rs;
    //rs.close();
    //stmt.close();
    //stmt=null;        
}
```

Where st string (statement) contains `select count(*) from mySchema."table1" where "col1" >=1` created with:

```
String st="select count(*) from mySchema.\"table1\" where \"col1\" >=1";
```

While this query works fine from PL/SQL Developer or Toad, in JDBC this query doesn't work returning null in `rs` object probably due to "Table or view does not exist" error related with using double quotes.

The stack trace shows:

```
sie 06, 2020 12:27:59 PM oracle.jdbc.driver.DBConversion StringToCharBytes
FINER: 5BFA9431 Enter: "select count(*) from mySchema."table1" where "col1" >=1"
sie 06, 2020 12:27:59 PM oracle.jdbc.driver.DBConversion stringToDriverCharBytes
FINER:          Enter: "select count(*) from mySchema."table1" where "col1" >=1"
sie 06, 2020 12:27:59 PM oracle.jdbc.driver.DBConversion stringToDriverCharBytes
FINER:          Return: [B@6a84a97d
sie 06, 2020 12:27:59 PM oracle.jdbc.driver.DBConversion stringToDriverCharBytes
FINER:          Exit [1.9144ms]
sie 06, 2020 12:27:59 PM oracle.jdbc.driver.DBConversion StringToCharBytes
FINER: 5BFA9431 Return: [B@6a84a97d
sie 06, 2020 12:27:59 PM oracle.jdbc.driver.DBConversion StringToCharBytes
FINER: 5BFA9431 Exit [7.3871ms]
sie 06, 2020 12:27:59 PM oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleSql getSqlBytes
TRACE_30: 4E3958E7 Return: [B@6a84a97d
sie 06, 2020 12:27:59 PM oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleSql getSqlBytes
TRACE_30: 4E3958E7 Exit [39.8323ms]
sie 06, 2020 12:27:59 PM oracle.jdbc.driver.DBConversion getServerCharSetId
FINER: 5BFA9431 Enter: 
sie 06, 2020 12:27:59 PM oracle.jdbc.driver.DBConversion getServerCharSetId
FINER: 5BFA9431 Return: 873
sie 06, 2020 12:27:59 PM oracle.jdbc.driver.DBConversion getServerCharSetId
FINER: 5BFA9431 Exit [1.7472ms]
sie 06, 2020 12:27:59 PM oracle.jdbc.driver.DBConversion getNCharSetId
FINER: 5BFA9431 Enter: 
sie 06, 2020 12:27:59 PM oracle.jdbc.driver.DBConversion getNCharSetId
FINER: 5BFA9431 Return: 2000
sie 06, 2020 12:27:59 PM oracle.jdbc.driver.DBConversion getNCharSetId
FINER: 5BFA9431 Exit [1.8433ms]
sie 06, 2020 12:27:59 PM oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection sendPiggyBackedMessages
FINER: 5606C0B Enter: 
sie 06, 2020 12:27:59 PM oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection sendPiggyBackedMessages
FINER: 5606C0B Exit [0.0354ms]
sie 06, 2020 12:28:00 PM oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer processError
SEVERE: 3514A4C0 Throwing SQLException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exists
```

Is there any way to workaround this problem within Oracle JDBC in Java?

Comment: Why you put "table1" and "col1" inside " "?

Comment: Because without doublequotes ORACLE is trying to find table name/column name in uppercase which is a common naming convention... so this query:

select count(*) from mySchema.table1 where col1 >=1 
for oracle is the same as:
select count (*) from MYSCHEMA.TABLE1 where COL1>=1

and it doesn't work in TOAD/PL/SQL because there is no table: MYSCHEMA and there is no column: COL1 in my database...

Comment: @altano , are you catching the oracle exception ?? in this case , which is it ??

Comment: How are you embedding the quotes within the `st` String? Is the query returning an error, or no rows; or you have a problem accessing the value from an `rs.getXXX` call? If the latter show that too.

Comment: @AlexPoole
String st="select count(*) from mySchema.\"table1\" where \"col1\" >=1";

From the Oracle jdbc trace log (attached below):
ORA-00942: table or view does not exists

Comment: When you run this successfully in Toad etc., are you connected as the same user as you are in Java? (And to the same DB, of course). Wondering if the Java-connection user just doesn't have select privilege on that table in `mySchema`.

Comment: Oracle user is the same in TOAD & JAVA. I made additional test in JAVA using some simpler query "select sysdate from dual" -> this one works fine in java which shows problem is caused only by doublequotes jdbc driver is trying to send to oracle for execution:

sie 06, 2020 12:27:59 PM oracle.jdbc.driver.DBConversion stringToDriverCharBytes
FINER:          Enter: "select count(*) from mySchema."table1" where "col1" >=1"

Comment: There must be some way to escape these doublequotes but after spending a lot of time and trying different variants I have no more ideas how to do it correctly...

Comment: But the quotes are correct in the stack trace, so why do you think those are a problem? Being able to select from dual doesn't tell you anything about permission problems. You're getting ORA-00942 so the user you are connected as can't see that table in that schema. If you're 100% sure you're connected as the same user, copy and paste the statement from the trace and run that - maybe it's just a typo in the name? FWIW I tried your code and didn't have a problem with a quoted identifier.

Comment: @AlexPoole You were right ! I was connecting as an different user :) (due to wrong app configuration :) Thanks for help !

Comment: If there is any Oracle naming standard, it's usually, do not quote your object names and avoid case sensitive/reserved words.